# How does the non-static method of a class is getting called statically from another different class' method without creating the object of former?

Tags: php, class, object, non-static

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

Consider below code :

```
<?php
  class A {
    function foo() {
      if (isset($this)) {
        echo '$this is defined (';
        echo get_class($this);
        echo ")\n";
      } else {
        echo "\$this is not defined.\n";
      }
    }
  }

  class B {
    function bar() {
      A::foo();
    }
  }

  $a = new A();
  $a->foo();

  A::foo();
  $b = new B();
  $b->bar();

  B::bar();
?>
```

Output of above code :

```
$this is defined (A)
$this is not defined.
$this is not defined.
$this is not defined.
```

Except the first line in the output the next three lines of output have been generated by calling the non-static method `foo()` which is present in `class A` statically(i.e. without creating an object of `class A`).

Someone please explain me how is this happening?

How does the non-static method from another class is getting called statically from the class/ object of class under consideration(i.e. `class B` here)?

Thank You.

Comment: Enable error reporting

Comment: @PeeHaa : How to make it enable? I mean what's the code for it? Where should I add the corresponding code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: use `ini_set("display_errors",1);`  at the top of the code for enabling the error

Comment: Tried that code **using PHP 7.1.1** too, with `ini_set("display_errors",1);` and everything works fine too. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: PHP is very loose with static vs. non-static methods

But: Methods which are not static should NOT be called statically (*even if PHP is tolerant*). Why?

If a method is not static, this usually means that it is depending on the state of an instance, because otherwise it **could be made static**.

Sometimes a non-static method is not dependent on an instance and therefore a program still works, because this method could be static. **But you never should do this**.

Furthermore - if you turn on error reporting, PHP will also tell you this:

> $this is defined (A) 
>  **Deprecated**:  Non-static method
>   A::foo() should not be called statically in **[...][...]** on line
>   **25**
>  $this is not defined. 
>  **Deprecated**: 
>   Non-static method A::foo() should not be called statically in
>   **[...][...]** on line **18**
>  $this is not defined. 
>   **Deprecated**:  Non-static method B::bar() should not be called
>   statically in **[...][...]** on line **29**
>  
>   **Deprecated**:  Non-static method A::foo() should not be called
>   statically in **[...][...]** on line **18**
>  $this is not
>   defined.

The Deprecated also means: *Just because PHP still allows this, it will most probably be removed in future PHP updates.*